# I am getting error when I use sort function in the list

Tags: python

```
cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']
x = cars.sort()

print(x)
```

I am getting None value when I run this code please help me.

Comment: `list.sort()` is in-place method. Try using `sorted(cars)`

Comment: I got the answer

Answer (score 2):

this is because `sort()` function don't return anything and sort your `list` you don't need x, you can use cars like below:

```
>>> cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']
>>> cars.sort()
>>> print(cars)
['BMW', 'Ford', 'Volvo']
```

Answer (score 1):

sort function do not return any value just sort

```
cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']
cars.sort()

print(cars)
```

Comment: so where do you sort in your code example? this is not helpful